# Rails route with dynamic slug followed by child ID

Tags: ruby-on-rails, routes

In my model, a Seller has many Items.

The Seller is accessible via its slug, not its ID:

**config/routes.rb**

```
get "/:slug", to: "sellers#show"
```

This works fine.

However, I want each item URL to include its parent slug according to the format `/:slug/:id`, e.g. `/piano_man/5` or `/joe_schmoe/344`.

The following works:

**config/routes.rb**

```
get '/:slug/:id', to: 'items#show'
```

**app/controllers/items_controller.rb**

```
def show
  @item = Item.find(params[:id])
end
```

But it (clearly) does not change the default Item URL behavior because this code just ignores the :slug part.

How can I make the default URL `<%= link_to item %>` point to `/:slug/:id` instead of `/items/:id`?

Remember that the "slug" is from the parent model `Seller`, but the ID is from the Item itself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need to name the custom Seller's Item route and then refer to that named route in your use of link_to:

**config/routes.rb**

```
get '/:slug/:id', to: 'items#show', as: 'seller_item'
```

**app/views/items/index.html.haml**

```
= link_to item.name, seller_item_path(slug: item.slug, id: item.id)
```

That should work, as far as I know... There might also be a way to override `to_param` on your Item model to return slug and id, instead of having to specify them as arguments directly to `seller_item_path`.